# Change timezone for datetimepicker

Tags: php, jquery

My datetimepicker(jquery.ui.datepicker.js) shows the server time, when the "NOW" button is clicked. Is it possible to show the "Current local time in Hamilton, Canada", while clicking the NOW Button? i.e.,Is it possible to make the datetimepicker should work in accordance with the Hamilton time? Please help.

Comment: Being that jQUI is all client side, wouldn't it show the local time according to the settings on the client computer?

Comment: 'now' on the server would still be the same as 'now' on the client-side. What you should do is make sure your server is set to UTC and let the client do the conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JavaScript uses the time settings in the user's operating system.. You can pass the timezone settings to the server side, and do conversion between timezones (i.e. if you want to store UTC in the database).

Answer (score 0):

Canada... Hmmm so that is -4Hours UTC?

This can help you:

```
$(".timepick1").datetimepicker({ 
    dateFormat: $.datepicker.RFC_2822, 
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm z', 
    showTimezone: true,
    timezoneList: [
            {"value": "-0400", "label": "Time in Canada"}, 
        ]
});
```

or if you do not wish to show the timezone:

```
$(".timepick2").datetimepicker({ 
    dateFormat: $.datepicker.RFC_2822, 
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm z', 
    showTimezone: true, 
    timezone: "-0400" 
});
```

Comment: Y not write a php script to check the month and date? and just change it accordingly? I mean, come on! I gave a solution, don't be so harsh :(

Comment: I just wanted to point out this important fact, was not trying to be mean about it. So let me expand a little bit on this..

The thing is, it's a really bad idea to rely on timezone offsets.. You should basically never do it, and always rely on regions. In this case it should be 'Canada/Eastern'. There's a lot of subtle details that will end up being incorrect with just the offset, it's just too much to explain in this comment box.

Comment: But I doubt that this jQuery plugin would support such a region, so the correct calculation would then have to be done on the server. So my only point was that.. although your solution may just be all the OP needs, if the OP needs accuracy, then the solution is flawed. Nothing personal ;)

Comment: I tried the above two solutions. It doesn't work for me. Datetimepicker still shows the server time only.

Comment: @Evert I do not advocate the use of JS for time settings, but, with respect to server time you can always add / minus the time ;) Though, this is not the ultimate solution! But, was giving a workaround.